# Intersection of buffer with polygon layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer, intersection

I have a polygon layer representing land cover, and a layer of buffers around specific points.

[image: Land use and buffer layer]

I want to intersect the layers to later measure the proportion of each land-use in each buffer zone. However, I get an error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'difference'"

So I assumed I had errors in my land-use layer. I used the 'check geometries' tool and created a new "test" layer covering all my buffers to see where the error could be. After a few corrections, I can now intersect my "test" layer and my "buffer" layer; my "land-use" layer and my "test" layer, but still not my "land-use" and "buffer" layer - the error is still the same.

[image: Intersection of test and land-use]

I can't find what could go wrong.

---

You can find my layers [there](https://we.tl/SBkgyN6Obh)

Comment: It seems that you have problems with some features (if this is the case, you should repair their geometries). Could you share both buffer and landuse layers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by updtating my version of QGIS (I had 2.16) to the new version (2.18).

After that I was mysteriously able to intersect my layers.

Comment: Well done! I wouldn't find any problems because I'm also running QGIS 2.18.